Pattern fill in highcharter bar chart
I would like to create a column or bar chart with pattern fill in an R shiny app. It seems to me that highcharts and related highcharter package should be able to do the job, but I could not find a way. Here is what I tried based on this page:
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/pattern-fills
    library(highcharter)



hchart(iris,
       type = "column",
       hcaes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length))%>%
  hc_plotOptions(
    series = list(
      borderColor = "blue",
      color= list(
        patternIndex = 0
      )
    )
  )


Fill patterns are implemented in a separate module which you have to add as a dependency using hc_add_dependency("modules/pattern-fill.js"):
library(highcharter)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'quantmod':
#>   method            from
#>   as.zoo.data.frame zoo

hchart(iris,
  type = "column",
  hcaes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)
) |> 
  hc_add_dependency("modules/pattern-fill.js") |> 
  hc_plotOptions(
    series = list(
      borderColor = "blue",
      color = list(
        patternIndex = 0
      )
    )
  )


